# Scala Test JAR file with argument

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scalatest

I'm using spark 2.0, sbt 0.13 and Scala Test 3.0, I would like to know if how can I pass arguments from command like to test JAR file like the way I do the main JAR file.

For e.g, `spark-submit my-test-file.jar args1 args2`, and test cases in my test suite can get value of args1 and args2.

Answer (score 0):

please wrap those in to a property files maybe testcase.properties or .conf and use like below...

```
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions –Dlog4j.configuration=file:///spark/conf/log4j.properties -
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions –Dlog4j.configuration=file:///spark/conf/log4j.properties -Dapplication.properties.file=hdfs:///some/path/on/hdfs/testcase.properties
spark.application.properties.file hdfs:///some/path/on/hdfs/testcase.properties
```